# Can I let the community pick the best answer?

Tags: discussion

I solved the problem I was facing but used none of the suggested answers, can I let the community pick the best answer?

Answer (score 9):

The community's "favorite" answer to your question will automatically bubble to the top based on the answer that gets the highest score (a composite of all the +1 upvotes and -1 downvotes for each answer).

If *you* think an answer that's been provided is the best out of the available answers, you can click the green checkmark to accept it as the answer that was useful *to you*. The green checkmark is **only** there to indicate to others what the *original poster of the question* believed was the most useful answer, not what the community at large thinks. The community's "best answer" is the highest scored answer.

There is no technical mechanism in place for anyone except the original poster of the question to accept an answer with the green checkmark, and this will not be added based on many past discussions on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com), for the reasons I've summarized here.

You are welcome to answer your own question with the solution you used. If you find your answer to be the most useful answer *for you*, you are free to accept your own answer. If you also think other answers to your question are *helpful* or *useful*, you can upvote them to support the people who took time to answer your question. If you think some other answers are particularly bad and not useful, downvote them.

Comment: Yup, and upvote the helpful ones. Not that much difference between a +10 for upvotes and a +15 for selected answer.